# How do I duplicate a part in eagle?

Tags: eaglecad, osx

I just modelled a P-Channel MOSFET in Eagle and now would like to do duplicate the device to make slight changes to both the symbol and the device for a similar N-Channel MOSFET.

**I've searched and googled but I can't seem to find a way to copy the entire device to do this.**

Comment: As far as I know, you can duplicate a symbol (selecting the group command, then enclosing the entire symbol with a rectangle, then selecting a copy command; then creating a new symbol and doing a paste).  But you can't do this for a device; there is no copy or paste commands in the toolbar for a device.  So you have to take your new symbol, make a new device, and reassign a package and pins to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create the new symbol:

Go to the library.

Create a new symbol for the N channel FET.

Go to the symbol for the P channel FET.

Group all of it, then do CUT.

Go back to the new N channel symbol.

PASTE

Modify from there.

Then create the new N channel device, referencing the new symbol.

Comment: Olin is correct.  In case anyone is confused, the CUT command in Eagle acts more like a COPY :)

Comment: @bitsmack: Yes, Eagle has some strange command names.  As you mentioned CUT does a COPY, and the actual COPY rarely does anything useful.  Another one is how WIRE is used to draw lines except when they represent wires, then you have to use NET.